# How to link linux remote server's ip 1.2.3.4:8080 to projects.example.com/app?

Tags: linux, debian, web-server, reverse-proxy, jira

I have Remote Debian linux server which i access using Putty console either by IP or domain.
That means server IP is pointing to hostname already for example:

1.2.3.4  -> projects.example.com

I have installed Application called JIRA on remote server which is Apache based i guess. and i can access its website using 1.2.3.4:8080  I want to link this to projects.example.com/jira

How can i do that? Any details with tutorial link will ofcourse help.

Comment: What version of JIRA are you installing? 4.4.x or 5.0 Beta?

Comment: Its 4.4.3 on Debian 5 Linux.

Comment: I don't know where mysite.com points for you, but where I'm at it's _blocked_ because our system lists it as spyware. In the future, please use the name "example" for this kind of thing, as it's specifically reserved for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JIRA runs as a standalone tomcat container out of the box. You can easily proxy to it from apache, I've only configured it as a separate subdomain and not a subdirectory of a site (ie. jira.mysite.com vs. projects.example.com/jira.

This is the tutorial I used to setup our apache => Jira config using mod_proxy: 
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/Integrating+JIRA+with+Apache

To run it on a subdirectory like /jira, It may be as simple as doing this in your vhost:

```
ProxyPass /jira http://localhost:1080/
ProxyPassReverse /jira http://localhost:1080/
```

And setting the context path in conf/server.xml:

```
<Context path="/jira" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" reloadable="false">
```

Comment: Do i have to install Tomcat server other then standalone jira already running? I tried to configure context path /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml on server like it shows on documentation, but unfortunately the server is not accessing jira from http://1.2.3.4:8080/jira  Here is the line:
 <Context path="/jira" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" reloadable="false">

Comment: One last question: How to set my domain projects.example.com/jira instead of 1.2.3.4/jira ? If website is already pointing to that will it work? Or there's any configuration?

Comment: Hi sunny, You won't need any additional config on the JIRA side of things. Just an A record with your domains DNS provider pointing to the server's IP and the ServerName attribute set in your vhost

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with NGINX if you only want to do this simple proxy without running a full web server.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    servername projects.example.com _;

    location /jira {
        rewrite ^/jira(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8080;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_set_header                Host            $http_host;
        proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```